# Azure Cloud - AKS - azureblob-nfs-premium - Storage Account Naming

Tags: azure, kubernetes, storage, azure-aks

Hey folks of the Azure Cloud,

I'm trying to deploy an app into my AKS Cluster with persistent Storage in "Storage Account".

I created a PVC in K8s YAML using the "azureblob-nfs-premium" storage class.

Now I want to give the newly created Storage Account a specified name. But I really don't know how to do that.
Any tips or ideas?

[image: random name of storage account]

My (Helm) K8s PVC YAML File:

```
{{- if .Values.persistence.enabled }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: {{ include "project.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "project.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: {{ .Values.persistence.storageClass }}
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: {{ .Values.persistence.size }}
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the storage account is [dynamically provisioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5004151) you can't set a specific name for the Azure resource.

You can add tags to the resource by using annotations:

```yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
...
parameters:
  ...
  tags: costcenter=3333,team=beta
```

If you want to have full control you can switch to [static azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5004151), but those work different.

Comment: Seems like you were going to add a link to some docs, don't hesitate to do so! Or else you can remove that bottom part of your answer :)

Comment: You are right, but moved them into the text itself as links to make it more clear. Cleaned up now.